# URL Redirect created over SSL only works over SSL

Tags: uri, redirection

I have added a redirect via:

> Configuration > Search and Metadata > URL Redirects

While accessing the site via SSL. When I add the link the from box auto fills the root of the redirect with `https://myRootURL.com/` :

[image: URL Redirects Page]

This redirect works for `https://myRootURL.com/redirectedLink` but does not work for non-ssl: `http://myRootURL.com/redirectedLink`. I would expect all of these redirects to be ssl/non-ssl agnostic - and the ones auto-generated by Drupal all seem to be.

Is this a configuration issue - or known problem? I have had no luck with Google or browsing the [known issues](https://drupal.org/project/issues/redirect?text=https&status=All&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All), but I am not sure I am articulating the problem correctly.

**EDIT:** I am experiencing the same functionality with URL Aliases as well... what configuration options could impact this?

Comment: The redirect module don't save in database the full URL, only the URIs (source and target, plus language). You can see the infos in the "url_alias" table of your db. So there is no reason this doesn't work with HTTPS, it should be protocol (and domain name) independent. I would suggest to check the HTTPS and Apache conf.

Comment: That would have been my expectation, but my results are easy to see this is not the case somehow (whether how they are stored or something else) and that it does work for all of the auto-generated redirects. Working on access to the database now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am feeling a little sheepish here:

Caching was turned on for anonymous users. When accessing the site as `https` I was also logged into Drupal, unlike when I was accessing the site over `http`.

As such the anonymous users were not getting the redirect or alias applied until the cache was cleared. Should have been an obvious first step.